# Can I put BC in bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm using overleaf.com to write a report on Aristotle. In my bibliography, I want to put

```
year = 350 BC
```

Is this possible? I've loaded the package

```
\usepackage[isbn,issn,url]{dk-bib}
```

Which is basically Bibtex but in Danish

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you *really* have an edition of Aristotle of 350 BC? Papyrus? `;-)` You should use the date of the edition you're using.

Comment: And you should not use `BC` for Aristotle anyway. If you did need the date, you'd want `BCE`.

Comment: year = {350 BCE}

Comment: @user94293. The spirit of BibTeX would require that the input is language independent, I think, such that you can use a `bib` file with any `bst` file like `fr-alpha.bst` `dk-unsrt.bst`...

Answer (score 1):

In your Bibtex `.bst` file, you could replace the function `format.names` with the following

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year empty$
    { month empty$
        { "" }
        { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
          month
        }
      if$
    }
    { year #1 #1 substring$ "-" = 
         { year #2 global.max$ substring$  " " * "BCE" *}
         { year }
      if$
      month empty$
         { }
         { month " " * swap$ * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

This is a bit dirty because `year` is actually treated as a string literal by the bibtex engine. Bibtex test the first non-white character of the `year` entry and if it is a minus sign, it will skip it and write it as you wish. For the danish version, you should replace the string `"BCE"` by the appropriate expression. In your `.bib` file, enter the year as `year="-350"`.